# Ideology query: reconstructive vs pre-loaded method on PHP

Tags: php, theory

Well, I do not know if I can post something like this here. But I'm pretty sure all this is the correct place where we can discuss new ideas to improve our knowledge. Right?

I was thinking about this: when using PHP as an APACHE module, each request to a PHP file generate a new process to run your code. Generally we load multiple files (`include`'s) and perform various procedures as well. So guess where we ran a "index.php" the whole process is repeated several times and several whenever necessary.

A pratical example: if we ran a specific index.php that load 10 classes, PHP will parse all files and execute interesting parts, if need. It'll generate an I/O usage, of CPU, Memory and Storage.

```
<?php

    require_once 'classes/File.php';
    require_once 'classes/Event.php';
    require_once 'classes/Mobile.php';
    // ...

    File::emptyDir('tmp');

?>
```

It'll load every classes, parse and execute it. Ok.

So, in an ambient that I not need execute the required file too many times, just once, and only uses your methods, if I create a socket ambient to use that to each user request, can overspeed PHP access by avoid redundances?

A simple example of an user interation:

1. User start a request `/page?version=1.3`.
2. The `.htaccess` redirect to `request.php` engine.
3. The engine check if exists an idle pre-loaded service (`service.php`'s socket) and use that. If do not, start a new service (pre-load your code) and use that.
4. Send user data (as `$_SERVER` and `$_GET`) to service (as JSON for instance), it will turn to WORKING state.
5. Service will return user data to `request.php` again. And turn it to IDLE to be used in the next request. And will close after a very long IDLE time.

The question is: this method can overspeed PHP, by avoid parse all code everytime (excluding opcode optimizer), preparing classes, etc.?

I think about some theorical de/advantages:

- GOOD: possibly will turn request very fast;
- GOOD: will avoid load every time the same file, or create a new process everytime;
- GOOD: will be possible to control every thread instances and your states;
- NEUTRAL: if you change some file, you need close all services to create a new with updated files. Solution: just avoid that, in a devopment ambient, every main request will start a new service.
- BAD: will use memory for more time, instead of free that after every request;

Comment: What about all the global variables whose values need to be different for each run of the script? Anyway, this isn't really the place to discuss design changes in webservers and PHP, this is for practical programming questions.

Comment: "What kind of questions should I not ask here?

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask